# Scrapy: scraping JSON data from URL that is constructed with dates

Tags: javascript, python, json, scrapy

I have read many posts on using Scrapy to **scrape** JSON data, but haven't found one with dates in the URL.

I am using Scrapy version 2.1.0 and I am trying to scrape this [site](https://alight.kujakuja.com/en/ideafeed) which populates based on date ranges in the URL. [Here](https://pastebin.com/5Fmze4fS) is the rest of my code which includes headers I copied from the site I am trying to scrape, but I am trying to use the following `while` loop to generate the URLs:

```
while start_date <= end_date:
    start_date += delta
    dates_url = (str(start_date) + "&end=" + str(start_date))
    ideas_url = base_url+dates_url
    request = scrapy.Request(
        ideas_url, 
        callback=self.parse_ideas, 
        headers=self.headers
    )
    print(ideas_url)
    yield request
```

Then I am trying to scrape using the following:

```
def parse_ideas(self, response):
    raw_data = response.body
    data = json.loads(raw_data)
    yield {
        'Idea' : data['dates']['data']['idea']
    }
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/26A3Qq4V) is a more complete error output from when I try to runspider and export to a CSV, but I keep getting the error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Is this the best approach for scraping a site that uses dates in its URL to populate? And, if so, what I am doing wrong with my JSON request that I am not getting any results?

---

Note in case it matters, in `settings.py` I enabled and edited the following:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/4537.36'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

COOKIES_ENABLED = False
```

And I added the following at the end of `settings.py`

```
HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES = [400]
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that you are trying to scrape a JavaScript app. In the html it says:

```html
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
```

Another problem is that the app pulls it's data from [this api](https://api.alight.kujakuja.com/api/v3/responses/ideas) which requires authorization. So I guess your best bet is to either use Splash or Selenium to wait for the page to load and use the html generated by them.
Personally I mostly use something very similar to [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium). There is also a Package available for it [here](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-selenium/)